# Load Multiple PowerBI Embedded Report Simultaneously

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I've 7-10 PowerBI embedded report display side by side using IFrame as shown in image.
[image]
Issue is I have to click `signIn` button for each report individually. so I have to click  7-10 times. I am using Embedded url. I cannot use any other method except Iframe that is restriction for me

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To achieve single sign-in experience, we need to build a custom integration by using the users-own-data embedding method. Refer to limitations section in [Embed a report in a secure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-embed-secure#considerations-and-limitations)